# Modify date when receiving it from database

Tags: angular, date-formatting

I have a table where I can update Dates in an input field.

When I add a date to database on another table I format the date for the database so that it can handle it for example: `Tue Feb 11 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)`, after formatting it looks like this: `2020-02-11` and it is saved like that in database.

When I want to update this date and I get the date back from database, but this format is not loaded inside the `DatePicker` field. I know I have to format it back but I can't figure it out what can be a good solution for this.

I am using angular 7.

Comment: may be moment Date adapter will help? https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material-moment-adapter

Comment: example from documentation https://stackblitz.com/angular/bqmdjddvlmq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-formats-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using JavaScript Date objects, you can convert a string that has the 'yyyy.MM.dd' format into a JavaScript Date object like this:

```
let myDateString = '2020-02-11';
let myDateObject = new Date(myDateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

So I made a mistake and didn't checked properly what's the data in the database looks like and since the data type was nvarchar(80) the data i got back was `'2020-02-11         '` with a lot of white spaces and that's why the picker wasn't showing the proper date. I used a simple `trim()` function and now it works good.